# Xamarin forms with .netStandard 2.0, can't reference Core

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I can't reference my Interfaces from my .Core project to my Android Project and I don't understand why...

I created a new solution with Visual Studio 2017 in Xamarin.Forms with .Net Standard lib.

And this is what I tried:

[image]

With the old .NetFramework Core project method, it worked perfecly, but not now...

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is vague and hard to understand, Xamarin has nothing to do with core, The way to do this is only reference .Net standard libraries from Xamarin or.Net Core. Thats why they are standard.. not the other way around

Comment: @TheGeneral When I speak about Core, I want to speak about the project when you develop. When I read the documentation of netStandard, they speak about implementation to create CustomRenderer, but, as you can see, I can't implement Interface from the main project...

Answer (score 1):

Ok i understand what you mean now, and i have experienced this before

1. Make sure your .Net Standard project compiles
2. Remove and Add the .Net Standard reference back to your Andriod projects

Also try deleting all you bin and object directories for all your projects and restart visual studio and compile again

Xamarin can be very fickle, it will work but you need to make sure it doesn't get confused in the process

Comment: Already tester that. I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with Resharper. I spent 2 hours in this problem... I'm going to try with my Mac tomorrow.
But, yes, my project compile and I can deploy, and, reference has been removed and added again. Bin and obj already deleted. Visual studio run in admin mode

Comment: @Naografix so is App1 a .net standard library?

Comment: Yes, .NetStandard 2.0, I can share my solution if you want

Comment: @Naografix no im on my way to work, however you need to just keep fiddling with this, it will eventually work, try to make sure everything is up to date as well.